# learn wanIP with router (wget)

Tags: linux, bash, wget

Question asked through an translator:

In centos need to know the Wan IP at the router and save it to a file through CMD.

Top of the line is:

```
 wget http://user:pass@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)\.\(.*\)'
```

That it is necessary to add that line in the file ex. test.txt?
Page looks like this:

```
<TABLE border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=0 width=100%>
<script>
var info_get_wanip="213.121.21.121";
var info_get_wanmask="255.255.255.255";
var info_get_gateway="0.0.0.0";
var info_get_dns1="83.111.121.10";
var info_get_dns2="83.111.121.14";
var ppp_uptime="338946";
var bpa_uptime="0";
var monthly_limit_reached="0";
```

I need to write data from info_get_wanip in test.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
wget -O- http://user:pass@192.168.1.1/RST_conn_status.htm       \
| perl -ne '/var info_get_wanip="((\d+\.){3}(\d+))"/ and print $1'  \
> test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much for correct answer, you saved my brain :) I added only "var info_get_wanip" because there were several "info_get_wanip"